# How to aggregate multiple results in to JSON array of objects in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a pretty complex query which pretty much does what I need and at the end produces a result set that looks like this:

```
id sub_id name  tags
1  1      Test1 Tag1
1  1      Test1 Tag2
1  1      Test1 Tag3
1  2      Test2 Tag1
1  2      Test2 Tag4
```

What I need is to return these results as JSON that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "sub_id": 1,
        "name": "Test1",
        "tags": [
            "Tag1", "Tag2", "Tag3"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "sub_id": 2,
        "name": "Test2",
        "tags": [
            "Tag1", "Tag4"
        ]
    }
]
```

How do I do it using Postgres JSON functions? I was trying various grouping functions but no joy so far. Here's what my query is so far:

```
SELECT a.*, at.tag AS tags FROM names a
    INNER JOIN (SELECT id, sub_id FROM tags WHERE tag IN ('Tag1', 'Tag3')) AS mt ON a.id = mt.id AND a.sub_id = mt.sub_id  -- optionally only include names that have "Tag 1" or "Tag3"
    INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM tags) as at ON a.id = at.id AND a.sub_id = at.sub_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use ***[`json_build_object`](https://www.sqliz.com/postgresql-ref/json_build_object/)*** method along with ***[`json_agg`](https://www.sqliz.com/postgresql-ref/json_agg/)*** to achieve your requirement. Something like:

```sql
WITH combined AS (
    SELECT a.id, a.sub_id, a.name, t.tag
    FROM names a
    JOIN tags t ON a.id = t.id AND a.sub_id = t.sub_id
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tags WHERE id = a.id AND sub_id = a.sub_id AND tag IN ('Tag1', 'Tag3'))
)
SELECT
    json_build_object(
        'id', id,
        'sub_id', sub_id,
        'name', name,
        'tags', json_agg(tag)
    )
FROM combined
GROUP BY id, sub_id, name
ORDER BY id, sub_id;
```

***[DBFIDDLE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t2t4ABdFy3V6Bp6ehhBXeK/0)***

Comment: Yup, I was trying to avoid building object explicitly, hoping I can find a way to automatically map all the columns, but this approach also works, thank you!